# Clicking on a button | Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, button, click

**Website: https://eljur.ru/login.**
This is a site where I want to enter data and parse the login page. But there is a problem: I know how to click on the buttons, but here at the beginning there is a field "Выберите образовательное учреждение"("Choose an educational institution") where you need to click and a search will appear, where you also need to find your school.
*Please help me make it so that I can click on "Выберите образовательное учреждение"("Choose an educational institution") and go to the school search.*[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng9Mn.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0yyK.jpg)

I tried to find element with class "form-select-button--icon-left" and also "form-select-button_placeholder" and click but nothing worked.

Comment: The webpages through the URL and snapshot doesn't looks to be same. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code. Since you seem to be a new contributor, am sending you the complete class.

```
package basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated;

public class Eljur {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static final Duration TIMEOUT_DURATION = Duration.ofSeconds(30);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://eljur.ru/login");
        customWait(1);
        findElement(By.cssSelector("div[role='combobox']")).click();

        findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-input__input")).sendKeys("Y");
        findElements(By.cssSelector("div.form-select-option")).get(0).click();
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void customWait(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000L);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static WebElement findElement(By by) {
            return waitFor(visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    }

    public static List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
            return waitFor(numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(by,0));
    }

    public static<T> T waitFor(Function<WebDriver,T> function) {
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT_DURATION)
                    .until(function);
    }
}
```

Comment: findElements(By.cssSelector("div.form-select-option")).get(0).click(); What does get(0) mean in this line?

Comment: When we enter search text, that list is populating multiple data. So, am taking all of them and then choosing the first available value.